VS Code cant find R on Fedora
When setting up the R extension in VS Code on Fedora it is not able to find R.
When using the radian path obtained with which radian, I get the following error:
The terminal process "/home/justus/.local/bin/radian '--no-save', '--no-restore'" failed to launch (exit code: 1)

Using which R yields:
Cannot find R client at /usr/bin/R. Please check r.rterm setting. 

Interestingly, the VS Code terminal also does not find R or radian.

Just to be sure, your settings.json file has "r.rterm.linux" = "/home/justus/.local/bin/radian" and you can launch both R and radian outside of VS Code?

Yes, that is exactly the case

If the VS Code terminal can't launch/find R or radian, that sounds like more a permissions issue to me. I wonder if either of the solutions in this SO answer may help?

Thank you, this inspired me to look into the installation method

The solution was, that I had to reinstall VS Code. I moved from the Flatpak version I was using before to the yum repository described on the official VS Code docs, where R is now recognized in the terminal. So it was probably related to the reduced permissions due to the Flatpak sandboxing.
